# System of Equations involving exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

I would like to solve the system:

> $$2^{x+y^2}+2^{x^2+y}=8 $$
>   $$\sqrt x+ \sqrt y =2 $$

I have come up with a solution that is not rigorous, but somehow it gives the right solution:

Expanding the second equation:

$$x+y +2\sqrt {xy}=4$$

Squaring again
$$(x+y-4)^2 =4xy$$

$$x^2+y^2-2xy-8x-8y+16=0$$

$$2^{ x^2+y^2-2xy-8x-8y+16}=1$$

Rewriting the expression in the form:

$$2^{x^2+y^2+x+y} =2^{9x+9y+2xy-16}$$

Now I let $a(x,y)=2^{x^2+y}$ and $b(x,y)=2^{y^2 +x}$, and let $f(x,y)$ be the right hand side of the above equation, then we have:

$$a+b=8$$

$$ab=f(x,y)$$

Without justification, I use quadratic formula by treating $f(x,y)$ like a coefficient, I get:

$$a(x,y)=4 \pm \sqrt{16-f(x,y)}$$
$$b(x,y)=4 \mp \sqrt{16-f(x,y)}$$

Since $a(x,y)=a(y,x)$ based on the expression given from quadratic formula,

$$2^{x+y^2}=2^{x^2+y}$$

Factorize:

$$(x-y)(x+y-1)=0$$

$x=y$ or $x+y=1$

At this point it is easy to verify that $x=y=1$ is the only solution.

> Question: Is my method of applying quadratic formula to a function valid? What are the only ways to solve this question?

Comment: we have $$2^a+2^b\ne 2^{a+b}$$ in the general case

Comment: How about taking $u =\sqrt{x}, \; v = \sqrt{y}, \; g(w_{1}, w_{2}) = -4 + 2^{w_{1}^{2} + w_{2}^{4}}$ (for the root, pick and fix a branch).  Then your system becomes:
$$
u+v=2, \quad g(u, v) + g(v, u) = 0.
$$
The first of these is a line (in the $uv$-plane).  The second equation could not be met if $u^2 + v^4 > 2$, because then we would have $g > 0$.  That puts $(u, v)$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $(0, 0)$.  Furthermore, the second equation specifies curves in the $uv$-plane.  Therefore, we are looking for intersections between that curve and the line $u+v = 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By quadratic-arithmetic inequality, we have $$(x+y)\geq \frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{2}=2.$$

Similarly, $$(x^2+y^2)\geq\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\geq 2.$$

Also, by arithmetic-geometric inequality, we have  $$2^{x+y^2}+2^{x^2+y}\geq 2\sqrt{2^{x+y^2}2^{x^2+y^2}}\geq 2\sqrt{2^{4}}=8.$$ Here equality holds, which is possible only if $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$.

Therefore, $x=y=1$ is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was clean